# Filter Results From 'STUFF' Function

Tags: sql-server

I need to filter the results from my STUFF function which are held in the column 'combined_ops'. I need to only see records that do not contain the word 'Transfer'. I've tried the classic WHERE combined_ops NOT LIKE '%transfer%', but does not work. See my code and results and please let me know where I went wrong. Thank You.

```
SELECT Job, STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '  ' + Operation_Service
                   FROM dbo.Job_Operation
                   WHERE dbo.Job_Operation.Job = dbo.Job.Job 
                   for xml path('')),1,2,'') AS combined_ops
FROM  dbo.Job
WHERE dbo.Job.Status = 'Active' 
AND   dbo.Job.Customer_PO = 'tmi stock'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G887P.png)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is that to say you don't want a `Job` row if any associated `Job_Operation.Operation_Service` contains `transfer`? Or is it that you don't want those `Job_Operation` rows to be concatenated but you do want any others for the same `Job`? If the latter you can just add a `WHERE` predicate on the inside of the subquery. If the former you will need to use an `APPLY` for the subquery

Comment: @Charlieface, the former is what I'm trying to accomplish. How would I go about using APPLY like you stated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

You can put the `FOR XML` in a `CROSS APPLY` and filter afterwards

```sql
SELECT
  j.Job,
  jo.combined_ops
FROM  dbo.Job j
CROSS APPLY (SELECT
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '  ' + jo.Operation_Service
           FROM dbo.Job_Operation jo
           WHERE jo.Job = j.Job 
           for xml path(''), type
          ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'')
) AS jo(combined_ops)
WHERE j.Status = 'Active' 
  AND j.Customer_PO = 'tmi stock'
  AND jo.combined_ops NOT LIKE '%transfer%'
```

Or you can use `HAVING` and conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT Job,
       STUFF((
          SELECT '  ' + jo.Operation_Service
             (
               SELECT jo.Operation_Service
               FROM dbo.Job_Operation jo
               WHERE jo.Job = j.Job
               GROUP BY jo.Operation_Service
               HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN jo.Operation_Service LIKE '%transfer%' THEN 1 END) = 0
               ) jo
          for xml path(''), type
         ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') AS combined_ops
FROM  dbo.Job j
WHERE j.Status = 'Active' 
  AND j.Customer_PO = 'tmi stock'
```

Note the use of the syntax `for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)')` to unescape XML characters correctly.

Note also the use of table aliases rather than three part column names.

Comment: I've accepted the answer! I tried to upvote, but I'm not allowed to yet haha I need at least 15 reputation to vote. #facepalm